# Delete major version powershell csom

Tags: powershell, versioning, csom

I have a document library where i have uploaded documents it has 2 major versions and i want to delete the first major version. Is there powershell csom code i can used to do this

Answer (score 0):

**Connect to your SharePoint Site**

```
# Bind to site 
#
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("Your URL") 
$Credentials =  Get-Credential -Message "Enter your credentials for SharePoint Online:" 
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Credentials.UserName,$Credentials.Password)

# Get Web Object
#
$Web = $Context.Web
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Get Object of the uploaded document**

```
$Upload = $Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($fileUrl)
$Context.Load($Upload)
```

**Get versions of file and delete them**

```
# Get versions and delete
$Version = $Upload.Versions
$Context.Load($Version)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#[0] is the first version, and its ID is 512
$Version[0].DeleteObject()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```